# Is DataMembers one for everyone or unique for every client?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

I want to use wcf to share some data between clients using BasicHttpBinding (client is Xamarin.Forms app). I want to build it using this:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

...but before i starto to work, i want to know is DataMembers created one and only for every client or service create unique for every client. Someone tried something like this before?

Comment: Read [ask] and elaborate on your question. It's really unclear what you mean by "DataMembers created for every client". `[DataMember]` is an attribute you can put on properties of a DTO.

Comment: Sorry, it's my "English".

Step by step:

1. Service:

DataMember element: message = "something 1" (by default)

2. Client1 "set" it to "something 2".

3. Client2 come and "get" message.
He'll get "something 1" or "something 2"?

Comment: In WCF, you create a response to a request. That response only goes to that request.

Comment: WCF is on my "need to learn" list, but isn't `DataMember` a property of `DataContract`, which is merely a message? A message to server, which needs to do something with the message. So, based on my minimal knowledge, the answer is no. You need to persist the information somewhere server-side to be able to send it back on second request to another user.

Comment: :/

I'm gonna use mysql database. Thanks for help.

Comment: What. How is a MySQL database a replacement for a SOAP interface like WCF? Are you going to expose your database over the internet?

Comment: No, its just small app for LAN. I already did small wcf service using DM/DC and i'm gonna connect it to mysql database. It's gonna be like mysql<->wcf<->xamarin.

Yes, i would use SOAP messages, but i have no time. Deadline. After deadline i'm gonna try something more.